# Static image exporting (Plotly) crashes Python

Tags: python, image, svg, jupyter-notebook, plotly

Whenever trying to export a plotly image in vector format using `fig.write_image("name.svg", width=1920, height=1080)`, JuypterNotebook's kernel keeps running. Eventually, I have to interrupt the kernel.

What could be the culprit?

Comment: A bug I imagine. Report it to the maintainers of the code at fault.